# Redirect from javascript in asp razer view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have following Jquery code the code is sending data to controller fine and now I want to redirect from here after success how can I achieve this

```
    $('#reply_admin').click(function () {
        var recipName = $('.input_eply').val();
        var id =@Model.id
        $.post('/Admincontact/Replt/' + id,
               { reply: recipName },
               function (data) {
                   $('#reply').append(data);
                   window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Admincontact")';
               });

    });
```

and my controller is

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Replt(string reply,string id)
    {

        EmailManager.admin_reply(db.contactUs.Find(Convert.ToInt32(id)).Email, reply);
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

Comment: I think that should work, check console for errors.

Comment: Is it possible that `$('#reply').append(data);` throws an exception?

Comment: yes,but chrome console and firebug are showing no exceptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whats the meaning of

```
  $('#reply').append(data);
```

If you are returning `EmptyResult()`

Try only

```
 function (data) {

                   window.location.href = '@Url.Action("Index", "Admincontact")';
               }
```